Advanced database queries from frontend to Spring Boot backend
I'm developing an internal tool with a Vue.js frontend and a Java Spring Boot 3 backend. One of the key features I want to include is an advanced database search that allows users to retrieve database objects based on complex conditions without directly using SQL. I'm aiming for a seamless path from the frontend form to the database, with minimal backend interference.
Currently, I'm facing a challenge with querying entities based on child entities that have various relationships, particularly OneToMany. For example, I need to search for a Library entity that includes a Book with the name "foo" AND another Book with the name "Bar".
I've tried using RSQL and found the rsql-jpa-specifications project, which is promising but does not support conditions on multiple child objects as required by my scenario. I also explored GraphQL, but it seems that I would need a significant amount of custom coding to fit my needs.
While theoretically possible to handle with RSQL using a parser linked with various JPA specifications, this approach seems overly cumbersome due to the complexity of my data model and the extensive mapping required. I believe my needs are not so unique, so I'm hoping there might be simpler existing solutions.
So all I want is a way to make queries from my frontend, similar to what exists in the RSQL ecosystem. But with the ability to have advanced conditions like my example with Library / Book. Technically, this would translate to multiple JOINs or EXISTS conditions.
Does anyone know of any Java/Spring Boot-based solutions, or perhaps solutions in other languages, that could facilitate this kind of advanced query functionality? Or, if you've implemented a similar feature, could you share how you approached it?
Thanks for your help!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please add an example of what the UI will send to the backend, and what would be the expected query the backed needs to run.
